# two different python paths

Tags: python, python-2.7, environment

I created a new environment in python version 2.7 in my anaconda 3 environment. While the environment I created should work with python 2.7, it works with python 3 due to other environment. How can I fix the path, I encountered two different paths. I want to choose the path where 2.7 is.

[here is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srCoi.png)

can you help with this problem

Comment: You could use `python2` instead of `python`

Comment: I'm already using python 2. But while python 2's path should come, python 3's path is.

Comment: you could edit windows' %path% environment variable